# dkms versus module-assistant

Tags: debian, dkms

`module-assistant` has been the de-facto method of compiling and building binary Debian packages containing kernel modules for a while now. More recently a comparable utility has appeared - `dkms`.

If anyone has experience using both, please do a compare and constrast on the advantages and disadvantages of using one versus the other.

One item to address in an answer is whether `dkms` builds binary Debian packages for kernel modules too, and if so, how, and if so, what the differences between the packages built by `m-a` and `dkms` are, if any.

I have personally never used `dkms`, but I have used `module-assistant` sporadically over many years, and it has been a good experience. I don't have immediate plans to experiment with `dkms`, so I don't think I am the right person to write an answer.

Random googling found a discussion [here](http://www.linux-archive.org/debian-development/488898-future-m-dkms.html), also [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2008/09/msg00229.html).

Needless to say, any answer should be based on first hand experience, not copying from web forums. A worked example using both would be nice. Possibly `nvidia-kernel`, since that is quite commonly used. Yes, I know it is a proprietary kernel module. :-(

UPDATE: Thanks to jordanm for his answer. I'd like something that goes into a little more detail about what is going on under the hood, for both `m-a` and `dkms`, though I did not initially mention this. Also, it sounds like most of the time `dkms` will work transparently and automatically. But what are the failure modes of `dkms`. How do they both cope with manually compiled/installed kernels? Either installed from a binary package or a local install.

Comment: Those are not random web forums you linked to. They are actually discussions between Debian developers. They are quite old and dkms has made improvements since (such as handling multiple kernel versions).

Comment: @jordanm yes, i know what they are. And I can see they are (relatively) old. They were just intended as illustration that `m-a` and `dkms` are considered comparable.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference from a user's perspective is that `module-assistant` (`m-a`) is a tool to manually compile a kernel module, whereas `dkms` does it automatically without user intervention. If you are using `m-a` and the kernel package is upgraded, you must manually recompile the module using `m-a`. Since `m-a` only compiles for the kernel you are currently running, this means you will have a broken GUI for the next reboot if the module that you need `m-a` for is a graphics driver.

The triggers for `dkms` are executed on every kernel package installation and it ensures the module is installed for every kernel on the system. I personally can not think of a reason for an end-user to continue use of `m-a`.

Here are some examples of `m-a` vs `dkms` for the `nvidia` kernel module:

Building a module with module-assistant:

```
apt-get install module-assistant nvidia-kernel-source
m-a prepare # install the header package for the current kernel and compilation tools 
m-a install nvidia-kernel-source # compile the source into a .deb and install it
```

Building a module with dkms:

```
apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

Kernel upgrade with `module-assistant`:

```
apt-get upgrade # assumed to upgrade kernel
# reboot
m-a prepare
m-a install nvidia-kernel-source
```

Kernel upgrade with `dkms`:

```
apt-get upgrade # assumed to upgrade kernel
```

Comment: does dkms build binary Debian packages too? Also, can you indicate whether `m-a install nvidia-kernel-source` build and installs the binary module packages? I suppose in `dkms` the module is build transparently. What happens with manually compiled kernels?

Comment: You have two sections. The first two are just titled "module-assistant" and "dkms". Can you be more specific what these are for? The last two are clearer - "Kernel upgrade with module-assistant" and "Kernel upgrade with dkms".

Comment: `m-a` does build and install a debian package. `m-a` would not work with a manually compiled kernel, unless it was installed via Debian package. I am not sure how `dkms` would handle it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha clarification to examples added

Comment: Let us distinguish between the cases where a manually installed kernel was installed via a Debian package, and where it is not. If the latter, the question is whether the user would have the option to use either `dkms` and `m-a`. if the former (binary kernel package) I assume they would, but details would be interesting. I know `m-a` works with manually installed binary kernel packages, because I have used it with them. You do have to make sure to build the headers as well - which is another Debian package.

Comment: Consider adding comments about what lines like `m-a prepare` and `m-a install nvidia-kernel-source` do. The former installs packages needed for build and the kernel header packages, and the latter, builds and installs the kernel package, I believe.

Comment: You wrote "m-a does build and install a debian package." Yes, I know that. I was asking about `dkms`.

Comment: You can use `m-a` to build for non-running kernels with the `-k` option, I believe.